# Learning java. Problems with audio control

Tags: java, audio

I'm new to java and trying to add sound to my application. The problem I'm having is that the music starts but it doesn't stop when the music method is called for the second time. What am I doing wrong?

```
import sun.audio.*;
import java.io.*;

public class sound {
    private static boolean playing = false; 

    @SuppressWarnings("restriction")
    public static void music() {        
        try  {
            // open the sound file as a Java input stream
            String soundFile = "backgroundmusic.wav";
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(soundFile);

            // create an audiostream from the inputstream
            AudioStream audioStream = new AudioStream(in);

            // play the audio clip with the audioplayer class
            if(playing == false){
                AudioPlayer.player.start(audioStream);
                playing = true;
            }else{
                AudioPlayer.player.stop(audioStream);
                playing = false;
            }
        } catch(IOException error) {}   

        System.out.println(playing);                
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you call `music()`, a new input stream is constructed, so you are working with absolutely different stream instances between method calls.

Comment: Ah ofcourse, now that you say its pretty obvious. Thanks for the help.